# Form's Design - Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

My code run but when i try to show form design i get Class not registered.

```
 at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance (Guid & Clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid & iid)
    in System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore (Guid Clsid)
    at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance ()
    at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate ()
    at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.set_Site (ISite value)
    in System.ComponentModel.Container.Add (IComponent component, String name)
    in System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd (IComponent component, String name)
    at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent (Type componentType, String name)
    at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance (Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
    at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance (Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
    at the System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeInstance (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object [] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
    at the System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ComponentCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeInstance (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object [] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
    in System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
    at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
    in System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
    in System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
    at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName (IDesignerSerializationManager Manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)
```

Comment: Do you have an ActiveX control? Is the control registered as 32-bit only or 64-bit only?

Comment: I don't think so, but i already try to change all for 86x.

Comment: You are using the ActiveX Host in your form control, so I assume you are using an ActiveX control. The issue may be that Visual Studio is running as a 64-bit process, but can't load the 32-bit ActiveX, or vice-versa.

Comment: when i ignore the problem it shows the design but some DataGrid dissapears.