# Failed to load VB.Net form: "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) "

Tags: vb.net, com, windows-10, interop

I'm trying to upgrade an old VB.NET application (which currently runs on Windows XP), to Windows 10. I did an auto update from a VS2010 to a VS2017 project, but when I try to open one of the forms, I get an error in the designer:

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
>   Instances of this error (8)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid,Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.set_Site(ISite value)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component, String name)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component,String name)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstanc>e(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ComponentCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)

I found a couple of related issues (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877728/forms-design-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/95ad5557-eee5-4749-bbe7-b896c8ac97bb/error-0x80040154-in-vbnet?forum=vssmartdevicesnative)), all saying I need to register some COM/ActiveX component.

My question is how do I find the offending component? The exception info does not specify its GUID.

So far I've tried:

- set target to x86
- regsvr32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, that doesn’t look like you have built it with a pdb, that should be your first step, see if it doesn’t give you a line number.   If that doesn’t work, then you’ll have to open up the *.design.vb file manually delete things until you don’t get that error.

Basically it’s a bit tedious, but not difficult if you understand how things happen in the designer — basically it’s just another class and everything it does you can do manually.

Comment: Actually, I simply put breakpoints in *.design.vb. Took me log(n) to find the offending control :-)